# Rails4 - Child model association depending on Parent model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, has-one

I have a User model that has an occupation attribute.
Let's say a user can be a `footballer` or a `tennisman`
When the user sign up, he selects the occupation, and can change it later.

My User model contains the most common attributes, like name, address, weight, contact infos.
I want to store the other specific attributes in dedicated models, such as footballer_profile, tennissman_profiles

I can not use polymorphism since the infos are too different for a single model structure.

How can I declare to my User model a specific has_one condition depending on my "User.occupation" attribute ?

And is it the best way to go ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  enum occupation: [ :footballer, :tennissman ]

  self.occupations.each do |type| 
    has_one type, -> { where occupation: type }, class_name: "#{type.classify}_profile"
  end
  #..
end
```

Please read [#enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to understand how it works. Just *remember*, while you will be declaring, an attribute as *enum*, that attribute must be an ***integer*** column. If you don't want to go with *enum*, use a constant.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  Types = [ :footballer , :tennissman ]

  Types.each do |type| 
    has_one type, -> { where occupation: type.to_s }, class_name: "#{type.classify}_profile"
  end
  #..
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that exactly what I had in mind.
However, the answer of Mike Campbell make me think twice about the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for polymorphism to me.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :occupational_profile, polymorphic: true
end

class FootballerProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :occupational_profile
end
```

This way you can simply build and associate the profile for the occupation they've chosen.

Comment: Did you read the question? It says **I can not use polymorphism since the infos are too different for a single model structure.**

Comment: That comment makes no sense, hence I ignored it. Polymorphism allows for completely distinct models to describe the additional profile information.

Comment: Sounds interesting. In my logic, the base element would be User since it is common, you reversed that.
How would you manage the user hability to change it's occupation ? I'm quite disturbed by the id stored inside SportProfile.
Same question about displaying the infos in view which result as FootballerProfile.user.firstname. However, you widered my mind :)

Comment: You can ignore the semantics around the wording of "belongs_to", it's not really important. Changing occupation is just a case of replacing the occupational_profile for the user, how you bake that in to your application logic is up to you. To display user information in a FootballerProfile view, you would do exactly as you said @footballer_profile.user...

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Until now, the visitor goes to the signup page and find here a form that will allow him to fill all infos - generale (user) + specific (sportprofile).
Which is easy with nested form + js (show hide field) and form_for (@user).

With polymorphic, the form_for would be different for each type of sport, which we didn't know yet.
Polymorphism require a dedicated form, with a two steps : 1 - select your occupation 2 - fill the infos inside form_for(@sport_profile), calling a sportprofile#new action. Not the best for this case I think. Still interesting however.